# Now where do I get my wood?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I *just* got Hearthfire for Skyrim and I was going to buy wood for my house when a blood dragon attacked me!

I killed it but I had seen him bite and throw someone. That someone was the person I get the wood from!

Now what?